# Error in jpa hibernate association many to one

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

This my Product class that extends a BaseClass and I get error in

```
 @JoinColumn(name = "fk_supplier",referencedColumnName = "supplier_id")
 private Supplier supplier;
```

and error is 'Many To One' attribute type should not be 'Supplier'

```
@Table
@Data
public class Product extends BaseEntity {
    @ManyToMany
    private List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<>();
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_supplier",referencedColumnName = "supplier_id")
    private Supplier supplier;

}
```

And this is my Supplier Class

```
@Table
@Data
public class Supplier extends BaseEntity {
    @Column
    private boolean active;
    @Column
    private Date foundationDate;
    //Enum type to String type in mysql
    @Column
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Type type;


    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Product.class)
    private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Comment: show error logs

Comment: May be you import wrong header file instead of you import your custom model class you wrongly import java.util.function.Supplier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`supplier_id` column is defined under which entity?, means in the provided snippet for `Supplier` entity no such field is present.
I hope the base entity will only be having columns that are generic and applicable over every entity you will be using. So if you specify `referencedColumnName` be sure that it align with what you have in the definitions. By default it will the primary key of the referenced entity, here primary key of `Supplier` table.

Please try to do like this, it may solve the issue i think

```
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_supplier")
private Supplier supplier;
```